# can't understand why can't use regular brackets instead of square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing an online course and can't understand why was square brackets use for this code and what does it do

```
enter code here

buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
gamePattern = [];


function nextSequence(){
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
var randomChosenColor = randomNumber[buttonColors];
gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
}
```

Comment: var randomChosenColor = randomNumber[buttonColors];    for this particular code

Comment: Its represent an `array` with objects in it.  a normal bracket will be one string of multiple color as one sentence like `buttonColors = 'red blue green yellow'`

Comment: You sure it isn't `buttonColors[randomNumber]`?

Comment: Which square-brackets in particular are you asking about and how would you have expected to use _"regular brackets"_ in their place?

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are right

Comment: @Phil i was thinking that randomNumber would *  to button colors and pick a random color

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are used to either describe an array literal, target an element of an array, or a target a property of an object.

The function `nextSequence()` appears to be:

- Generating a number 0-3 inclusive.
- Pushing a random color to the `gamePattern` array.

There is an obvious issue with the function in that the `randomNumber` and `buttonColors` are swapped.

The purpose of generating a random number 0-3 inclusive is to target an index of the `buttonColors` array. So instead what you want is the following:

```
function nextSequence(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you. I have added some explanation as well to what is `[]` array

Also you need to use `var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];` instead of `var randomChosenColor = randomNumber[buttonColors];`

You can read more about those brackets `[]` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) on JS MDN

Run snippet below.

```js
//Array with colors
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

//An empty array to add random color into
var gamePattern = [];

//Random number generator
function nextSequence(){
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);
}

nextSequence()

//Printing results
console.log(gamePattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets are a shortcut for an array https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Curly brackets are a shortcut for objects https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

That just the syntax, you don't need to understand why they are used like that, just need to remember which is which. For comparison JSON and other syntaxes/languages uses similar rules https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: I'm not sure _"shortcut"_ is the right word to use here

Comment: @Phil _shortcut_ in opossition to `var x = new Array();`

Comment: The word you're after is _"literal"_ as in _"array literal"_ and _"object literal"_

Comment: Wellp, in other languages i.e. PHP it's literally called _short array syntax_, which for me is synonym for shortcut. If you think it's wrong usage, feel free to edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

What we are dealing with here is covered under [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Let's break things down a little bit, to better understand what is going on.

First, we should know, all object properties, the keys, are "strings".
Second, we know we can use "." (dot notation) or ['...'] bracket notation to access an object's properties.

When we use dot notation, to access an object property, JavaScript will attempt to convert the key to a sting, before resolving it on the object.

Simple right... only not all property names will work.

Let's say we have an object like so:

```
var DigitWords = {
  //...
  "9": 'Nine',
  "+": "plus",
  "-": "minus"
}
```

You can not use dot notation to access any of these properties, as if you did

```
DigitWords.9
```

You would get an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number' error.

In order to get the property we need to use ["bracket"] notation like so:

```
DigitWords[9] or DigitWords['9']
```

We can use variable values too:

```
var $prop = 9;

DigitWords[$prop] // 'nine'
```

So, we can see the most flexible, and perhaps less error prone way to get a property, if it exists, is using bracket notation, and if you want to use a variable to get the property, bracket notation is the only way to go.